# Not getting a desired output from firestore database:

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project where I have a recipes database and in which there are several details such as recipe name, description, ingredients, rating etc

This is my database:[image: Database]

I am trying to get a recipe ingredients from database but it didn't gave me the output.

This is how I am getting data:

```
  Future<String?> getRecipeData(String recipeID, String key) async {
    try {
      CollectionReference recipes =
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes');
      final snapshot = await recipes.doc(recipeID).get();
      final data = snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      return data[key];
    } catch (e) {
      return 'Error fetching user';
    }
  }

  List<String> ingredients = [];
  ingredients = (await RecipeModel()
        .getRecipeData(widget.recipeID, 'recipe_ingredients'))!;
```

The getRecipeData returns me the correct value except recipe_ingredients. when I try to get recipe_ingredients it show me error fetching data.

Please help me to get the correct output. thanks

Comment: Can you print the value of e being catched. I think there is an issue with the function's return type.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar database scheme and when i want to retrive the data i use the following method:

```
Future<List<String>> getRecepieIngredients(FirebaseFirestore db,String recipeId)async{
    List<String> recepieIngredients= [];
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>> query = await db.collection("recipies").where("id", isEqualTo: recipeId).get();
    if(query.docs.isNotEmpty){
      LinkedHashMap<String,dynamic> map = query.docs[0].data()['recepie_ingredients'];
      for(var rec in map.values){
        recepieIngredients.add(rec);
      }
    }
    return recepieIngredients;
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).